# Prove that $\sum_{j = 0}^p {p \choose j}{p + j \choose j} \equiv 2^p + 1 ~(\text{mod}~p^2)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that $$\sum_{j = 0}^p {p \choose j}{p + j \choose j} \equiv 2^p + 1 ~(\text{mod}~p^2)$$

I have tried to write the problem as
$$\sum_{j = 0}^p {p \choose j}{p + j \choose j} - 2^p - 1  \equiv 0~(\text{mod}~p^2)$$
Which mean I have to prove that the expression on the left side is divisible by $p^2$, but this doesn't help.

I also know that since $p$ is odd prime, we have $2^{\varphi(p^2)} = 2^{p^2 - p} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod} ~p^2)$ by Euler's theorem. So the expression before can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{j = 0}^p {p \choose j}{p + j \choose j} - 2^p - 2^{p^2 - p} \equiv 0~(\text{mod}~p^2)$$
But this also doesn't seem to help. I think I have to modify the sum somehow, but I gut stuck. The sum looks like a hypergeometric function, but knowing this doesn't help either.

Anyone?

Comment: Note that by Lucas' theorem, for all $j\ne0,p$, $$\binom pj\binom{p+j}j\equiv\binom pj\pmod{p^2}$$

Comment: Also when $j=p$, by Wolstenholme's theorem we have $\binom{2p}p\equiv2\pmod{p^2}$

Comment: @EdwardH. Wow thanks! that help me alot. I didn't know (before you mention the theorems) both Lucas' Theorem and Wolsteholme's theorem, but I can prove both the congruences you gave me. Would you mind to write the hint as an answer so I can accept your answer? Thank you

Comment: @Azlif The result follows easily by using the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n.$